# How to run command line on startup ubuntu server

Tags: server

I want to run `vncserver` on startup How I can do it in startup file directly or create a custom Command via `alias` if possible

Answer (score 0):

1. First, install the TightVNC server  `sudo apt-get install tightvncserver`.
2. Set up the VNC server for the user you wish to log in as. When you run "vncserver" for the first time, it will ask you to set a password. only allow SSH tunnelled or VPN connections. To launch programs or a session when your VNC session starts, modify `~/.vnc/xstartup`. Here is an example.

   ```
   #!/bin/sh

   xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
   xsetroot -solid black
   /opt/azureus/azureus &
   k3b &
   icewm-session &
   ```
3. Copy the following into `/etc/init.d/vncserver`. The easiest way to do it is to copy it to your clipboard, run `sudo -i && cat > /etc/init.d/vncserver && exit` in a terminal, paste it in, and type CTRL-D. Be sure to change the USER variable to whatever user you want the VNC server to run under.

   ```
   #!/bin/sh -e
   ### BEGIN INIT INFO
   # Provides:          vncserver
   # Required-Start:    networking
   # Default-Start:     3 4 5
   # Default-Stop:      0 6
   ### END INIT INFO

   PATH="$PATH:/usr/X11R6/bin/"

   # The Username:Group that will run VNC
   export USER="mythtv"
   #${RUNAS}

   # The display that VNC will use
   DISPLAY="1"

   # Color depth (between 8 and 32)
   DEPTH="16"

   # The Desktop geometry to use.
   #GEOMETRY="<WIDTH>x<HEIGHT>"
   #GEOMETRY="800x600"
   GEOMETRY="1024x768"
   #GEOMETRY="1280x1024"

   # The name that the VNC Desktop will have.
   NAME="my-vnc-server"

   OPTIONS="-name ${NAME} -depth ${DEPTH} -geometry ${GEOMETRY} :${DISPLAY}"

   . /lib/lsb/init-functions

   case "$1" in
   start)
   log_action_begin_msg "Starting vncserver for user '${USER}' on   localhost:${DISPLAY}"
   su ${USER} -c "/usr/bin/vncserver ${OPTIONS}"
   ;;

   stop)
   log_action_begin_msg "Stoping vncserver for user '${USER}' on localhost:${DISPLAY}"
   su ${USER} -c "/usr/bin/vncserver -kill :${DISPLAY}"
   ;;

   restart)
   $0 stop
   $0 start
   ;;
   esac

   exit 0
   ```
4. Make the script executable with `sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/vncserver`.
5. Finally, connect to your server with a VNC client on port 590X, where X is the value of "DISPLAY" in the vncserver script. On OS X, I like to use Chicken of the VNC. On Windows and Linux, the TightVNC client works nicely.

<sub>[Source](http://www.abdevelopment.ca/blog/start-vnc-server-ubuntu-boot)</sub>